# Method with argument of AbstractController phpunit. Any hints

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I need to test method which looks like this, but my question is: How i should enter this method especially when i can not "mock" AbstractController, and without variable of AbstractController it would not work

```
public function add(\Queue\Controller\AbstractQueueController $task) 
{
       //Logic of method         
}
```

Comment: Why can't you mock it?

Comment: The good practice is not to mock AbstractClasses of Controllers, and also you should`t even test AbstractClasse. In this case i require object of abstract class to set it in public class of queue Service so it is exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mock it. You already set it as a parameter, so this test is not about testing AbstractQueueController.

So, for example, if your function looks like this :

```
public function add(\Queue\Controller\AbstractQueueController $task) 
{
   $task->doSomething();
}
```

Then, in the test,AbstractQueueController should receive a call to doSomething method(), and then assert the result of that.

Comment: Your hint were useful ,because i figured out ,how to test that part of a code, and what is the most funny thing it change state of another method and it start to return object, not a null state

Answer (score 0):

well i did something like that i made extended class

```
class addtest extends Queue\Controller\AbstractQueueController
{
    public function task() 
    {

    }
}
```

and then in my QueeuServiceTest extended by PHPUnit_framework_TestCase

i made testmethod

```
public function testadd()
{
    $this->queueService->add(new addtest);
}
```

it covers code but i do not know it is good practice